# jquery cannot get response from perl

Tags: jquery, ajax, perl

I want to use jquery to implement ajax response from perl script on the server.But when I use such code, I got nothing. I can get the result from the url in a browser, so I don't know where is wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){

$.ajax({
  'type': 'GET',
  'url': 'http://XXXX/cgi-bin/XXX.pl?title=dd',
  'async': true,
  'success': function(data) {
        alert(data);
  }
});

});
});
```

Comment: $("button") you mean all button element has this function when clicked or you meant something like $("#button") ?

Comment: If you use Chrome's Developer Tools - Network Panel, you can review exactly what ajax requests are made, and what the response was
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *url* field contain `http://server.domain/` and if you try to access a server from a webpage located elswhere than *http://server.domain/* (like in your desktop for sample, accessed via `file:///`), probably you need to add a field `Access-control-allow-origin: *` in the header sent by your perl CGI:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use CGI;
my $q=new CGI;

print $q->header(-type=>"text/plain", -Access_Control_Allow_Origin=>"*")."Answer";
```

Take care of security considerations...

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following diagnostic :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        alert('click happened');
        $.ajax({
            'type': 'GET',
            'url': 'http://XXXX/cgi-bin/XXX.pl?title=dd',
            'async': true,
            'success': function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert('ajax success: ' + [data, textStatus]);
            },
            'error': function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('ajax error: ' + [textStatus, errorThrown]);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Somewhere amongst the alerts (or lack of them) you should get a clue as to to what is failing.

Comment: it shows "ajax error: error". when I change the async to false, it shows "[Exception... "Failure"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 8416"  data: no]"

Comment: is it because what i returned from the perl is an html page with a table?

Comment: Ultimately, you will want an HTML fragment (eg just the table) rather than a whole page. But that doesn't explain why you currently get an ajax error. The most likely cause is that you are trying to query a different domain from that of the current page (ie a cross-domain request). If so, then you might like to try [this hack](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/) which claims to allow cross-domain GET requests. Definitely keep `async:false` - true is not supported in some browsers.